# On change of hidden select option jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, html-lists, html-select

I have used *tympanus natural language form* plugin. In which select option is `display:none` and it's working by `ul li` dropdown.

For validation, I have used **jquery validation** plugin.

> So on click `submit` button it's is validating and class is getting
>   added  to the target. But on change of dropdown, The class is not getting
>   removed. While on change hidden select option is validating.

Find image attachment below for better understanding.

[image: So on click <code>submit</code> button it's is validating and class is getting added the target. But on change of dropdown, The class is not getting removed. While on change hidden select option is validating.]

**[Find js fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/2dgmo4za/)**

I think, `Select option` event is not getting called in `ul li` dropdown. Because if I make visible `select option` and change by by select option then it works fine.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    onfocusout: true,   
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        return false;
    },
    highlight: function(element){
        $(element).addClass("errorHighlight-rrrr");
        $(element).prev('.nl-field').addClass("errorHighlight");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element){
        $(element).removeClass("errorHighlight-rrrr");
        $(element).prev('.nl-field').removeClass("errorHighlight");
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        $('.light').addClass('light_standActive');
    },
    ignore: [] 
}); 
$("#nl-form").validate({
    rules: { 
        movies: "required",
        restaurants: "required",
        refuelled: "required",
        fuelPrice: "required",
        groceries: "required",
        clothes: "required",
        equipment: "required",
        equipmentPrice: "required",
        travel: "required"
    },
    messages: {

    }
});
```

Comment: Play with the `close` event. `select` events will not work as they are in the background..

Comment: I tried hard and then I put on stackoverflow. Did you mean `closest` event? But there is not anything like select event is also getting triggered. `closest` doesn't help.

Comment: I don't see any code in your question.  (the jsFiddle would not count).  Please do not rely on a demo hosted elsewhere in lieu of posting a MCVE in the OP itself.   Thanks.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The plugin is triggered by events on the form elements.  Since the `select` element is hidden and changed into a `ul` via DOM manipulation, it can no longer trigger validation.  You're going to have to write a separate `change` handler that looks at when the hidden `select` is changed and then use the `.valid()` method to programmatically trigger validation.

Comment: Setting `onfocusout` to `true` almost always breaks this plugin.  The default functionality is already there.  [Please see the docs:  *"A boolean `true` is **not** a valid value."*](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout)